# How to Join Dynamic Graphics

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am just getting started with Mathematica and I want to join two dynamic plots that I'm playing with. They are generated by the following code:

```
Manipulate[ RegionPlot3D[ImplicitRegion[ Norm[{x, y}, p] <= z, {x, y, z}], Axes-> True], {p, 1, 10}]

 Manipulate[ContourPlot[Norm[{x, y}, p], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}], {p, 1, 10}]
```

I want to join the result of this code so that both graphics change together when p changes. Is it possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 {RegionPlot3D[
      ImplicitRegion[Norm[{x, y}, p] <= z, {x, y, z}], 
      Axes -> True], 
  ContourPlot[
       Norm[{x, y}, p], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]}, 
{p, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: I Can't give feedback on your answer since I don't have enough reputation. But it worked out perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: Can't you even upvote?  Oh well.   That's fine.  Maybe another time.